# Dúvida última linha no VBA

Tags: vba

Olá, estou escrevendo o seguinte código.

```
Sub DINAMICO()
    
Dim LINHA As Byte, PREENCHIMENTO As String, PREENCHIMENTOTWO As Currency, PREENCHIMENTOTRES As String

*Range("A1") = "PRODUTO"
Range("B1") = "VALOR"
Range("C1") = "SOBRENOME"
Range("A2") = "-"
Range("B2") = "-"
Range("C2") = "-"*

LINHA = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    
PREENCHIMENTO = InputBox("NOME")
PREENCHIMENTOTWO = InputBox("VALOR")
PREENCHIMENTOTRES = InputBox("SOBRENOME")

Range("A" & LINHA) = PREENCHIMENTO
Range("B" & LINHA) = PREENCHIMENTOTWO
Range("C" & LINHA) = PREENCHIMENTOTRES

End Sub
```

Porém, se eu tiro a parte que esta em itálico que no caso é a primeira linha que seria o titulo do que estou escrevendo juntamente com a primeira linha a macro não roda

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso o resultados está correto.

Se você tirar a primeira linha - `Sub DINAMICO()` - você está retirando a assinatura da função, que é o que diz à linguagem onde que começa o código. Sem assinatura nenhuma função funciona, em nenhuma linguagem de programação.

E se entendi direito, a outra linha que você está removendo é `Dim LINHA As Byte, PREENCHIMENTO As String, PREENCHIMENTOTWO As Currency, PREENCHIMENTOTRES As String` que é a declaração de variáveis. Novamente, sem ela é esperado que seu código não funcione.

Parece que você precisa pegar uns cocneitos básicos sobre programação. Dá uma olhadinha [neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsT3UDnEMYI)